# Where is my jar in Elastic Beanstalk EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to Elastic Beanstalk, but not to AWS.
I just spawn new EBS with sample java app (Java SE) and managed to make it run.
Since I'm used to create EC2 instance manually, I login into my EC2 but couldn't find where my sample jar app is deployed. My question is: where is my JAR deployed within EC2, in which directory?

Best regards,
Bromo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be AMI dependent you will need to check the document for the specific AMI you are using. It will either run your app with an embedded servlet container or it may have installed a Jetty/Tomcat and then you would be looking for a war somewhere. You could also use this approach of checking which jar/war the current Java process is using: https://askubuntu.com/questions/44043/how-can-i-find-out-which-jar-files-java-is-currently-running-and-their-pids

Answer (score 2):

FWIW with my AMI "runnable jar" it's in

/var/app/current

How to figure this out:
ssh to box, run `ps -ef | grep java` then `sudo ls /proc/<pid>| grep cwd` shows a symlink to its current working directory, and it's ps output showed it was running a local jar file relative to that dir.