# In which directory aws beanstalk host the application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

hello friends,
               I'm new to aws and linux environment,I've deployed a springboot application on beanstalk,now I want to know,In which directory my application reside or In which directory I can find 
through putty. thanks alot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is my jar in Elastic Beanstalk EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607347/where-is-my-jar-in-elastic-beanstalk-ec2)

Comment: Rails apps live in `/var/app/current`, but not sure about other applications.